# The bucket you tried to create is a domain name owned by another user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-deployment

I created a bucket with my domain.

But due to some payment related issue. I deleted that project in https://console.cloud.google.com and created a project with another id.

**Now when I am creating a bucket for it.  It gives me this error**

**How much time Google takes to delete a project**

**Or is any another solution for it**

Comment: Data is saved for closed projects for 30 days. However, I am not sure what happens when a bill is not paid. If you move your domain to Google Cloud DNS, that might get around the problem as your account will be the verified domain holder. However, that previous bucket just might stay locked away with the old project ID. The only solution if none of the above works is to contact Google Support.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I am not able to find my old project list in my previous id. they deleted from there.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: can I access my old deleted project from Google.

Comment: If your project is deleted, no. If your project exists, but is locked due to payment, no. I am not sure what you mean by "from Google".